# Program exit codes and their meaning in Windows Console applications

Tags: c#, windows, console, command

I'm developing a C# console application using .NET 5.0.

This is my code:

```
namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int portNo = -1;

            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: MyConsoleApp port");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(args[1], out portNo)) {
                Console.WriteLine("You have to pass a valid Internet port number.");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a doubt about what number do I have to return. I'm using `Environment.Exit(1);` to return 1 to the operating system but I'm not sure if this number is correct because I remember to use -1 with C++ programs.

Is there any documentation about these exit codes and their meaning?

Comment: They don't mean anything unless you document what exactly each exit code means for that particular application. `0` => success, `anything else` => failure

Answer (score 1):

There are some known codes for errors under Windows. See e.g.: [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

I suppose these are system error codes, that you can use to identify errors you experience in a known Windows application from Microsoft. That does not necessarily mean you should use the same codes yourself, but if you want some kind of guidelines, then I suppose these may be as good as any.

Personally, I would probably just use the universal "zero-value exit code" for "success" (i.e. `0` means *no errors*), and then add my own codes for whatever cases are needed later.

I think the default strategy of returningf "zero for success, non-zero for some kind of failure" is the most important thing here, as the output from your application may be used as input to another application or process.

Imagine for instance that your app is called from a script. The return value can then be used to decide whether to continue (if the return value was `0`), or if something failed, and the rest of the script should be aborted.